# Action expression in Decision table to add values to array or ArrayList

Tags: ibm-odm

Newbie to ODM here. Using decisiontable, I see I can do simple stuff like defining condition based on the variables IN from the variable set, and configure basic set value in the action columns

ex : set 'Field Name' to

I saw some examples online where you can use an expression like

```
add <a string> to 'Some Array Paramter'
```

Also, I see some examples where people use a reference to the object to call methods like

```
$obj.doSomething(<a string>)
```

I could use the latter to use the method in the Java class XOM to add that string to an array or something like that

But nothing seems to work

Any ideas how to acheive that?

Answer (score 0):

Any BOM method that returns void can be verbalized as an action phrase and used as an action in a decision table. Also, any BOM attribute that is writable can be verbalized as an action phrase and used in the same way.

Assuming you have a XOM and BOM defined, your Java classes and their public attributes and methods should appear in the BOM. If they are verbalized, you can use them to write rules (action rules or decision tables). Alternatively, you can create 'virtual' BOM attributes and methods manually in the BOM Editor and write B2X code for each of them that uses any Java classes, attributes, and methods in your XOM or the Java Libs.

You can verify what is available in your BOM using the Rule Explorer view in Rule Designer to browse the BOM. 
You can verify what is verbalized and available to write rules against in the Vocabulary view of the Rule Designer to browse the verbalizations.

Comment: Yes I can acheive that but lets say my sentence is " add {0} to {this} ", in the action expression in the Decision table is put " add <a string> to <a form query>".  Then the column splits in 2, I can put the string in the "string" column, but the form query object, what do I put? When using "set 'Some field' to <a string>", you don't define any object it is like implicit. How do I make sure the "object" I put in the action sub column is the one that goes into output?

Comment: Ruleset variables and rule variables (defined on General tab of decision tables) are available to fill in placeholders in verbalizations. You can specify them for each row of the table, like you described above.  Or you can specify them when defining the action column, which will eliminate the split column you describe, and that value will apply to all rows.